# "ImportError: No modules named pandas", but Mac Terminal shows "Requirement already satisfied"

Tags: python, pandas, macos, pip

I have a python script that utilizes the pandas module that is supposed to run on Mac OS. When I attempted to run the script, I received an error message stating "ImportError: No modules named pandas". I am very sure that I installed the pandas module using pip. Before attempting to run my code, I tried to prepare the machine for my code by running the following commands in the terminal:

- curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
- python3 get-pip.py
- pip install pandas
  According to the outputs on Terminal, everything installed properly and I am using the latest version of python. Specifically, when I ran "pip install pandas" i got the output that "Requirement already satisfied".

I have successfully downloaded pip and pandas. I am expecting a python script with pandas to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings in order:

> 1. pip uninstall pandas
> 2. python3 -m pip install pandas

It might be the case that it got installed in some other version of Python installed on your system.